# Playing a noise when an autocomplete function is visible with jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to be able to perform a jquery for when an autocomplete box is visible. 
I want to be able to hear this noise from this page 
http://www.wav-sounds.com/various/beep.wav

I have this code for my function so far, and the autocomplete works. I just dont know how to include that noise when it is visible.

```
                $("input[name=search]").live('focus', function() {
                    $(this).autocomplete({
                        source: myData,
                })
                });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the plugin from: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete ?

If so, the example at the bottom of the page looks like it will assist you.

```
$("input[name=search]").live('focus', function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: myData,
    }).result(function(event, item) {
        // code to play sound
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats great thanks, but how would I be able to apply it specifically for when the autocomplete drop down box is visible?

Comment: You would use a sound plugin and put the code to play the sound where the comment is above.  This should automatically play the sound after the autocomplete dropdown box is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
[JavaScript Sound Manager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)
or [jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)